# Django resolves one URL pattern, but not the other

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

My root url conf is

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^config-menu/', include('configuration.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('web.urls')),
)
```

and `configuration.urls` looks like this

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^$', ConfigHomeView.as_view(),
        name='config_home'),

    url(r'^address_labels/create$', AddressLabelCreateView.as_view(),
        name='address_label_create'),
)
```

Now observe this:

```
>>> reverse('address_label_create')
'/config-menu/address_labels/create'
>>> reverse('config_home')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ruben/v3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 551, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ruben/v3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 468, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'config_home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

How come I can resolve one, but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `''` after `patterns`

Like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ConfigHomeView.as_view(),
        name='config_home'),

    url(r'^address_labels/create$', AddressLabelCreateView.as_view(),
        name='address_label_create'),
)
```

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `patterns` is supposed to be the prefix, in this case probably `''`.

Comment: That did it. I'd even thought about that and thought I'd checked for it. Meh... To long day i suppose. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add `''` after patterns

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ConfigHomeView.as_view(),
        name='config_home'),
)
```

[Please see the patterns() docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#patterns)